# Что такое GNU? Что значит GNU/Linux

Tags: linux

Всем привет! Недавно начал изучать Python и постоянно мучает вопрос.
В начале я думал, что GNU — это оболочка для Linux: то есть Linux — это лишь командная строка, а GNU это именно как на Windows рабочий экран и ярлыки.

Сейчас осознал, что Linux — это ядро с открытым исходным кодом, а GNU — это программы с открытым исходным кодом, вроде так, поэтому в Linux нет Photoshop и т. д.

Я могу ошибаться, помогите понять новичку. Расскажите простыми словами или на примерах.

Comment: Вики: Свободная Unix-подобная операционная система, разрабатываемая Проектом GNU. Акроним GNU был выбран из-за того что GNU является Unix-подобной операционной системой, но отличается от Unix тем, что является свободным и не содержит его кода.

Comment: Само по себе ядро Linux (программа Linux) для конечного пользователя бесполезна. Вам же нужно как-то входить в систему, управлять пользователями, подключаться к сети, скачивать пакеты, «рабочий стол» и все типичные вещи? Так вот `GNU` — это как раз и есть набор таких вещей ОС, а `Linux` — ядро ОС. Они могут использоваться независимо. Например, есть система Android — там ядро Linux, а есть FreeBSD — там ядро свое (не Linux), но все остальное — GNU.

Comment: Лучше всего про это расскажет @aleksandr barakin.

Comment: GNU это рекурсивный акроним. Основатель GNU Ричард Столлман (в 80-х) говорил так --  `GNU's Not UNIX` (ну, для большинства же очевидно, что  функционально утилиты GNU это утилиты *nix-ов (Кстати, в проекте GNU предполагалось собственое ядро ОС -- Hurd)). Попытайтесь это обдумать в историческом контексте

Comment: *`"Что значит GNU/Linux"`* -- это GNU, где ядром ОС является Linux

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/104714/what-is-the-difference-between-unix-linux-bsd-and-gnu

Comment: Как иллюстрация от противного: был в своё время такой подпроект — Debian GNU/kFreeBSD. Это такой же дебиан, только не на линуксовом ядре, а на FreeBSD'шном. Абстрактная, так и не созданная система GNU предполагалась в виде GNU/Hurd.

Answer (score 9):

GNU — это набор из командной строки и утилит. Linux — это ядро системы. Ядро бесполезно без минимального набора утилит, а утилиты бесполезны без ядра. А GNU/Linux — это уже работоспособная ОС. На основе GNU/Linux делают дистрибутивы, например Debian. А к дистрибутиву добавляют (или нет) графическую оболочку.

В современных дистрибутивах часть утилит заменена. Например система инициализации в настоящее время systemd, управление драйверами и оборудованием делается через утилиты kernel (о), а часть утилит сети ставят из набора BSD.

Сейчас приставка GNU не имеет смысла, а служит лишь для того чтоб отличить операционную систему от её ядра.

Есть операционные системы Linux без GNU, например, OpenWRT. Есть с GNU но без Linux, например, Solaris, и есть сборки GNU для Windows.